# Maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

`I am reading about Zorns lemma and how one can show that every group contains a maximal abelian subgroup. I would like to ask what is the usage of this and if someone can describe this subgroup. I also know that there are groups without maximal subgroups. But if someone take the set of every proper subgroup of a group and use Zorns lemma in this I can tell that it has a maximal subgroup. What is wrong with it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "sinful"?  Do you mean "make sense of it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper-bound condition is not satisfied. The union of a chain of proper subgroups doesn't have to be a proper subgroup (recall that a maximal subgroup is defined to be actually a maximal proper subgroup!). Consider $(\mathbb{Q},+)$, it has no maximal subgroups, and in fact for example the union of the chain $\{\frac{1}{n!} \mathbb{Z} : n \geq 0\}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Every *finitely generated* non-trivial group has a maximal subgroup, though. In fact, if $C$ is a non-empty chain of proper subgroups, then its union $\cup C$ is proper, because otherwise we choose finitely many generators and observe that they are all contained in some single $U \in C$, but then $U$ would not be proper anymore.

Comment: Also why n! And not just n.and what is the usage of having a maximal abelian subgroup?

Comment: If $n \leq m$, then $n!$ divides $m!$ (but $n$ does often not divide $m$), and hence $1/n! \cdot  \mathbb{Z}$ is contained in $1/m! \cdot  \mathbb{Z}$.